# How can I use background-image inside a Bootstrap tooltip?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tooltip, background-image

I am trying to add an element that uses a `background-image` property inside of a Bootstrap tooltip, however the image is not displayed.

```html
<div class="big-panel">
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-title="Background image: <span style='display: block; background-size: cover;width: 32px; height: 32px; background-image: url(test/image.png)'></span> <br>Regular image: <img src='test/image.png'>">Hover me for testing</a>
</div>
```

[image]

I added a regular `<img>` tag in the same tooltip, and it works just fine. I just can't get the `background-image` property to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap tooltip component is designed to display HTML content, including inline CSS styles. However, it does not support applying background images directly through the background-image property within the tooltip's HTML content.

To achieve the desired effect of displaying a background image within the tooltip, you can use a workaround by applying a custom CSS class to the tooltip element and defining the background image in your CSS file.

First, add a custom class to the tooltip element, for example, custom-tooltip:

```
<div class="big-panel">
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-title="Background image: <span class='custom-tooltip-background'></span> <br>Regular image: <img src='test/image.png'>">Hover me for testing</a>
</div>
```

Then, in your CSS file, define the custom-tooltip-background class and set the background image:

```
.custom-tooltip-background {
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: url(test/image.png);
}
```

Make sure that the path to your image (test/image.png) is correct relative to the location of your CSS file.

With this approach, the background image will be applied to the element with the custom-tooltip-background class within the tooltip content.

Comment: Thank you @Zoubeir, that worked and set me in the right direction. Although, since I have a set of ~2000 different icons spread around in ~10 different spritesheets, how would I proceed with passing a CSS variable to the actual class?

I tried adding `background-image: var(--img)` in your code above, and `style='--img: url(test/image.png);'` in the <span> itself, however the variable does not seem to get passed over to the element. Is there a workaround to this without having a separate class for every image?

Comment: you can utilize JavaScript to set the variable value dynamically. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

Comment: HTML:
```
<div class="big-panel">
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-title="Background image: <span class='custom-tooltip-background'></span> <br>Regular image: <img src='test/image.png'>">Hover me for testing</a>
</div>```
CSS:
```
.custom-tooltip-background {
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    background-image: var(--img);
}```

Comment: JavaScript:
```
const tooltipElement = document.querySelector('.custom-tooltip-background');
const imageUrl = 'test/image.png'; // The URL to your image
tooltipElement.style.setProperty('--img', `url(${imageUrl})`);```

Comment: The problem with that code is that the `.custom-tooltip-background` element does not exist before the tooltip has been hovered on and cannot be accessed via JS. I tried using the `show.bs.tooltip` event listener, but couldn't manage to target the exact tooltip and the contents inside it. Is there something I'm missing? This doesn't seem that difficult but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: You are right, To dynamically set the background image for each tooltip, you can utilize the Bootstrap tooltip events and a combination of JavaScript and CSS.

Here's an updated approach:

Comment: HTML :
<div class="big-panel">
    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-title="Background image: <span class='custom-tooltip-background'></span> <br>Regular image: <img src='test/image.png'>">Hover me for testing</a>
</div>

Comment: CSS :                               .custom-tooltip-background {
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}

Comment: JavaScript :                                   
const tooltips = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
tooltips.forEach((tooltip) => {
    tooltip.addEventListener('show.bs.tooltip', function (event) {
        const targetTooltip = event.target.getAttribute('data-bs-original-title');
        const imageUrl = 'test/image.png'; // The URL to your image
        
        const tooltipElement = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-original-title="${targetTooltip}"] .custom-tooltip-background`);
        tooltipElement.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
    });
});

Comment: Nope, still unable to target the element. The `tooltipElement` always outputs `null`. I also tried changing the selector to `data-bs-title`. Here's the full code for better overview - https://pastebin.com/zdAW5Tpq . And the console output - https://i.imgur.com/jMFLg5x.png

Comment: The issue lies in the selector used in the querySelector method. The variable ${targetTooltip} is enclosed within single quotes instead of backticks. In JavaScript, template literals should be enclosed within backticks (```) to correctly interpolate variables.

To fix the issue, modify the JavaScript code as follows:

Comment: tooltipTriggerList.forEach((tooltip) => {
    tooltip.addEventListener('show.bs.tooltip', function (event) {
        const targetTooltip = event.target.getAttribute('data-bs-title');
        console.log(targetTooltip);
        const imageUrl = 'test/image.png';

        const tooltipElement = document.querySelector(`[data-bs-title="${targetTooltip}"] .custom-tooltip-background`);
        if (tooltipElement) {
            tooltipElement.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
        }
    });
});

Comment: In my code, I've added also a check (if (tooltipElement)) before applying the background image style. This ensures that the tooltipElement is not null before trying to access its properties. It prevents the error "cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')".

Now, the background image should be applied to the tooltip element when it is shown.

Comment: Oops, I missed the part where Stackoverflow turns ` into code blocks. The selector works now, however it outputs a string, not an actual element that can be modified with `style`. https://i.imgur.com/a9N0Asg.png